# Cascading Routers

Tags: networking

[image]

Can anyone help me here??

I have multiple routers in my office building. For now the Top floor router is the main router which is connected to the internet and other secondary routers to it. I have connected other routers with static IP to the Top main router and it is working fine.

Now I need to make the middle floor router the main router as it will be in the middle of the building. I am not being able to connect the middle floor router to the internet from the top floor router. And on top of that I also want to make the top floor router the secondary router so that all the routers share the same network making the middle floor router the Main.

It would have been solved if I could have brought the internet line to the middle floor but, it is on the top floor and is connected to the top floor router. I hope you all understand what I mean, this may be very simple but yet I am unable to configure it properly.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of "routers" are those? Are they the wifi/router/switch [combo](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31Fv9%2BW50AL.jpg) things, or are they _actual_ routers? What purpose do they serve?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help you out with this? You do not provide a map of the current configuration, nor of the desired one. You do no state whether dhcp is enabled on any of these routers, what their IP addresses are, whether you want your users to belong to the same subnet or you do not care, whether you want to enact VLANs. It would take a crystal ball to answer it. For now, I will propose closing this question. I will reconsider if you can add a sufficient amount of detail to make this answerable at all.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't see the image uploader as this is my first attempt. I have now uploaded the photo of the system.

Comment: There is no reason it matters which router is the main router. At least, if there is, you haven't explained it. What problem does changing which router is the main one solve?

Comment: What you are looking for is having one router and several mere access points (AKA "wireless bridges"). Most routers can act as such.

Comment: Yes that is what I have been using as such.

Comment: @grawity what would you mean by "actual router". I think people mean different things by that term. Some might mean a router/switch combo thing without a modem built in. Some might mean a cisco/juniper thing with no switch, so an IP on each interface and not via VLAN switch.  Some might mean a router with VLAN switch built in. Which of those do you mean when you ask if it's an  "actual router"?

Comment: I brought all the routers into one network now. But there has been a compromise that only the mac reservations from the 1st router is available which is for only 32 users. I want to use the mac reservations from all routers that will give 32 x 4 rooms that will allow only reserved users to access the network and even if the password is leaked there would be no problem, as no one else will be allowed to join the network that are out of the mac addresses reservations..

Answer (score 1):

The outside internet source is an ethernet cable, not a phone line or coax cable. Then the top floor router is not the modem.

**Where is the modem???**

An ethernet cable goes from the modem to the top floor router. Maybe there are cables going directly from the modem to the middle floor? Check that first!

1. Buy a switch, and use it to replace the top floor router.
2. Put the top floor router at the middle floor, next to the middle floor router.
3. If you need a top floor router, then you need to buy another router there. Will that change network settings for the top floor?

Now you can use the same setup. The only thing you changed is using an ethernet extension cord via the switch.

Comment: Thank you SPRBRN, All of them are the same model routers. The top floor router is connected via ethernet and is configured to PPPoE from where it gets the dynamic ip and dns addresses. Till now it passes the internet to other routers via LAN. Since other equipment are at the middle floor which will be connected to the middle router and it will be wiser to make the router main that reduces the journey of requests from users to the top floor. But, I still want to pass on the internet from the top router to the middle router and make the top the secondary to the middle router.

Comment: Not all Internet connections go through a modem...

Comment: One more thing is that all people connect to the internet through the routers wireless connections and all routers are connected to via LAN.

Comment: If all people use Wireless, then you could try to use one or more repeaters. If the floors are not too thick concrete, it might work well enough.

Comment: "**and it will be wiser to make the router main that reduces the journey of requests from users to the top floor.**" Seriously?! We're talking about *Internet* traffic that travels for miles and you're going to try to reduce the distance by a few feet? Are you nuts?

Comment: There were access points which I replaced with spare routers. I could have bought new ones but I thought of using the spares. I don't know why the printers make printouts from the commands sent one day earlier. It happens even when the printer, router and the computer are in the same room which is funny.

Answer (score 0):

The wording 'main router' would be ambiguous, if not for the fact you only need a single router. In your current setup, the router is on the top floor and the other devices, regardless of their capabilities, are used merely as switches. By necessity, the router is the device that seperates your local network from the internet. This cannot be done remotely; the middle floor router cannot do the routing between two networks whose boundaries are physically on another floor.

If for some reason, you want the device on the middle floor to act as the router and the one on the top floor to act as all the other ones (i.e. a switch), you'll need to extend the internet cable to that location and plug it into the router's WAN port.

Alternatively, as the question title suggests, you can use cascading routers by leaving the setup on the top floor as it is, and plugging its cable to the middle floor router (the blue one in your image) into its WAN port instead of its LAN port. This will create two seperate networks within your building. If I understand your question correctly, this is the opposite of what you want, in which case making the middle floor router the 'main router' is the opposite of what you need and your current setup is the correct one.

Comment: Yes Marcks I have used the cascading style from top floor router and still like to pass on the internet from it to all routers. Also want to make the middle router the central or main router. The reason behind using routers is because I had spare routers and next is that there be possibility of expanding the number of users in each floor.

Comment: @Rainbow: I think we're getting some terminology mixed up here. Functionally, all but one of these devices are switches, so I take 'main router' to mean 'the only router'. I think maybe you meant something else by it, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: They are all similar routers of the same brand and model. One of them (top router) is acting as router and the rest as switches.

Comment: I have achieved this but another problem has occured which is even more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I have suceeded in what I wanted somwhow i.e. I passed the internet through the Top Floor router to the middle floor router which is connected to another 2 similar routers that are on the same network making the middle router their main router. The middle and the 2 routers connected to it are in one network, this means that the top router cannot access them. I am now looking for solutions to bring the top router to the network that allows local networking with the middle router.